# How can I start a remote (Google Cloud) machine by opening SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Let's start with a short use case: Users want to connect to their remote workstations. While they can do so it costs a lot of money to keep all machines running all the time. Thus from the administration point of view the machines should be shutdown when they are not used / no user is connected.

Now the admins could give the users access to use the Google API to shutdown machines - but this means the users have to be `Compute Instance Admin` - which the admins obviously don't not want. Permission and access to the machines in this case is restricted with the help of SSH keys.

Thus: How can I start / stop a remote (Google Cloud) machine by opening a SSH connection?

I am open to any solution regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Creating and Managing Custom Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles)

> This is an Alpha release of IAM Custom Roles.

Using a Custom Role you should be able to limit your users actions based on your use case.

An alternative workaround could be [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) with some kind of authentication.

The simple SSH connection wont even initiate if the instance is not running. As well it would mean, you give 'start instance' right for *anyone*.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a way to do it. It does not solve starting the machine  on connection but nevertheless an interesting solution. Only problem would be that this is still alpha so Google might still change it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple bash script that starts the instance using gcloud and then pauses for some time while the instance is starting. It can then ssh to the instance.

Comment: The script still need authorization to run the gcloud command and without custom roles it means it has 'Instance Admin' role. The only workaround if the script is not modifiable, for example it runs as a Cloud Function.